# samsung galaxy note pro 12.2 won't play videos in youtube app without stopping

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, youtube

I am on a 100mbps internet. When I start playing youtube video it shows that it buffered a lot of it quick, but it is impossible to watch/listen to videos at it stops once in 10 sec and then autoplays in a few sec. itself.

I tried some other app to play youtube videos and they play fine.

What's wrong with my youtube??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to fix that.
I went to system settings > motion control and there I had "video set to pause when looking away". After disabling that it is not auto pausing anymore.